# PHP: get number of decimal digits

Tags: php, decimal

Is there a straightforward way of determining the number of decimal places in a(n) integer/double value in PHP? (that is, without using `explode`)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
$str = "1.23444";
print strlen(substr(strrchr($str, "."), 1));
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on extremely large or extremely small floats that get converted to scientific notation when represented as a string.

Comment: An example: `var_dump((string)(0.00000000000012));` outputs `string(7) "1.2E-13"`

Comment: @GordonM You can get around that with number_format: `$str = rtrim(number_format($value, 14 - log10($value)), '0');`.  14 is based on the maximum precision of floats in PHP; it may need to be reduced a bit if you're doing some math on the float first (especially if it was obtained by subtracting two larger numbers).

Comment: If using with a lot of numbers, it may be more efficient to just substract 1, instead of getting the substring: strlen(strrchr($str, "."))-1;

Comment: @GordonM Your solution is genius. But is depending on php not changing the precission sometime in the future or on rather unusual systems

Comment: @Brilliand This solution has a problem that the TypeError: number_format() expects parameter 2 to be integer, float given occurs.

Comment: @VijaySankhat Actually it works perfectly since you do have 2 decimals. If you'd like to do some kind of "rounding" on a string, then you can try something like `strlen(substr(strrchr(rtrim($str, "0"), "."), 1));`

Answer (score 24):

Less code:

```php
$str = "1.1234567";
echo (int) strpos(strrev($str), ".");
```

Comment: Clever. Just FYI if the number has no decimal point, `strpos` will return `false` instead of `0`

Comment: @andrewtweber updated :)

Comment: CLEVER!! Perfect!

Answer (score 14):

You could try casting it to an int, subtracting that from your number and then counting what's left.

Comment: Very good answear in my opinion, if I am right you must mean this: `echo strlen($num-(int)$num)-2;`

Comment: `$decimals = ( (int) $num != $num ) ? (strlen($num) - strpos($num, '.')) - 1 : 0;
` works with negative numbers too.

Comment: @EvanMattson that will not work for very large floats that overflow.

Comment: I was doing this in Dart, and this doesn't work because floating point subtraction is not precise, e.g. doing `(3.005 - 3).toString().length` got me 20. I expect this behaviour in any programming language?

Answer (score 13):

```
function numberOfDecimals($value)
{
    if ((int)$value == $value)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (! is_numeric($value))
    {
        // throw new Exception('numberOfDecimals: ' . $value . ' is not a number!');
        return false;
    }

    return strlen($value) - strrpos($value, '.') - 1;
}


/* test and proof */

function test($value)
{
    printf("Testing [%s] : %d decimals\n", $value, numberOfDecimals($value));
}

foreach(array(1, 1.1, 1.22, 123.456, 0, 1.0, '1.0', 'not a number') as $value)
{
    test($value);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Testing [1] : 0 decimals
Testing [1.1] : 1 decimals
Testing [1.22] : 2 decimals
Testing [123.456] : 3 decimals
Testing [0] : 0 decimals
Testing [1] : 0 decimals
Testing [1.0] : 0 decimals
Testing [not a number] : 0 decimals
```

Comment: note that php interprets a literal 1.0 in source as integer so when converted to string it does not have decimals. (even if you cast it to float at declaration so `$variable = (float)1.0;` ***does not work***)

Comment: This wouldn't work with very small or very big floats, which are output as scientific notation when cast to string. var_dump (strval (1/1000000));

Comment: This does not work in an international context, but with a little change it will:
`$localconv = localeconv();
return strlen($value) - strrpos($value, $localconv['decimal_point']) - 1;`

Answer (score 4):

I needed a solution that works with various number formats and came up with the following algorithms:

```
// Count the number of decimal places
$current = $value - floor($value);
for ($decimals = 0; ceil($current); $decimals++) {
    $current = ($value * pow(10, $decimals + 1)) - floor($value * pow(10, $decimals + 1));
}

// Count the total number of digits (includes decimal places)
$current = floor($value);
for ($digits = $decimals; $current; $digits++) {
    $current = floor($current / 10);
}
```

Results:

```
input:    1
decimals: 0
digits:   1

input:    100
decimals: 0
digits:   3

input:    0.04
decimals: 2
digits:   2

input:    10.004
decimals: 3
digits:   5

input:    10.0000001
decimals: 7
digits:   9

input:    1.2000000992884E-10
decimals: 24
digits:   24

input:    1.2000000992884e6
decimals: 7
digits:   14
```

Comment: Seems to fail in some cases, came by this on accident:
25.1234567890123 => 14 instead of 13

Answer (score 3):

I used the following to determine whether a returned value has any decimals (actual decimal values, not just formatted to display decimals like 100.00):

```
if($mynum - floor($mynum)>0) {has decimals;} else {no decimals;}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

test(0);
test(1);
test(1.234567890);
test(-123.14);
test(1234567890);
test(12345.67890);

function test($f) {
    echo "f = $f\n";
    echo "i = ".getIntCount($f)."\n";
    echo "d = ".getDecCount($f)."\n";
    echo "\n";
}

function getIntCount($f) {
    if ($f === 0) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($f < 0) {
        return getIntCount(-$f);
    } else {
        return floor(log10(floor($f))) + 1;
    }
}

function getDecCount($f) {
    $num = 0;
    while (true) {
        if ((string)$f === (string)round($f)) {
            break;
        }
        if (is_infinite($f)) {
            break;
        }

        $f *= 10;
        $num++;
    }
    return $num;
}
```

Outputs:

```
f = 0
i = 1
d = 0

f = 1
i = 1
d = 0

f = 1.23456789
i = 1
d = 8

f = -123.14
i = 3
d = 2

f = 1234567890
i = 10
d = 0

f = 12345.6789
i = 5
d = 4
```

Comment: This was the only solution I get.
Test: https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/73eup?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
<?php

$floatNum = "120.340304";
$length = strlen($floatNum);

$pos = strpos($floatNum, "."); // zero-based counting.

$num_of_dec_places = ($length - $pos) - 1; // -1 to compensate for the zero-based count in strpos()

?>
```

This is procedural, kludgy and I wouldn't advise using it in production code. But it should get you started.

Comment: I tried changing the sample value to an integer value, and the result says "2". What I'm trying to achieve is a process that will return 0 if the number is an integer, else the number of decimal places

Comment: When you say 'integer' did your integer have the form '10.00' or '10'?

Comment: Its value is 10. I'm expecting different kind of format such as 10, 10.00, 10.000. Based on the format, I will have to know the number of decimal digits used

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that takes into account trailing zeroes:

```
function get_precision($value) {
    if (!is_numeric($value)) { return false; }
    $decimal = $value - floor($value); //get the decimal portion of the number
    if ($decimal == 0) { return 0; } //if it's a whole number
    $precision = strlen($decimal) - 2; //-2 to account for "0."
    return $precision; 
}
```

Comment: This was great, but there's a shorter way to do it:  

is_numeric($value) ? max(strlen(strrchr(abs($value), ".")) - 1, 0) : FALSE;

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

```
$num = "12.1234555";
print strlen(preg_replace("/.*\./", "", $num)); // 7
```

## Explanation

Pattern `.*\.` means all the characters before the decimal point with its.

In this case it's string with three characters: `12.`

`preg_replace` function converts these cached characters to an empty string `""` (second parameter).

In this case we get this string: `1234555`

`strlen` function counts the number of characters in the retained string.

Comment: Perhaps this answer could be improved by explaining your code for OP

Comment: This use case will not handle values without decimals. This is correct implementation limited replace (to turn off global replace): `strlen(preg_replace('/[\d]+[\.]?/', '', $finalValue, 1))`

Answer (score 2):

**If you want readability for the benefit of other devs, locale safe, use:**

```
function countDecimalPlacesUsingStrrpos($stringValue){
    $locale_info = localeconv();
    $pos = strrpos($stringValue, $locale_info['decimal_point']);
    if ($pos !== false) {
        return strlen($stringValue) - ($pos + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

see [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)

Comment: I had no idea I did that. I approved it. Later that day I looked at this and found the edit not to have applied, so I changed it myself. No idea what happened.

Comment: Well it's still not there so I'm going to resubmit it.
The function does not work as is on floats that do not have a leading digit such as .25 or .3333 . (vs 0.25 or 0.3333). This is because $pos is 0 which evaluates to false. In this case, 0 is exactly the right answer, so we need to do a a type savvy check for $pos !== false instead. strrpos will return false if the decimal character is not found at all, but 0 if it is the first character in the string.

Comment: Thanks Phil, I ran some unit tests and it now handles values without a preceding number, E.g. .34

Answer (score 1):

```
$decnumber = strlen(strstr($yourstr,'.'))-1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Int

Integers do not have decimal digits, so the answer is always zero.

### Double/Float

Double or float numbers are approximations. So they do not have a defined count of decimal digits.

A small example:

```
$number = 12.00000000012;
$frac = $number - (int)$number;

var_dump($number);
var_dump($frac);
```

Output:

```
float(12.00000000012)
float(1.2000000992884E-10)
```

You can see two problems here, the second number is using the scientific representation and it is not exactly 1.2E-10.

### String

For a string that contains a integer/float you can search for the decimal point:

```
$string = '12.00000000012';
$delimiterPosition = strrpos($string, '.');
var_dump(
  $delimiterPosition === FALSE ? 0 : strlen($string) - 1 - $delimiterPosition
);
```

Output:

```
int(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
$iDecimals = strlen($sFull%1);
```

Comment: `$sFull = 3.1459287; echo  $sFull%1;`
Result: `0`. So: no.

Answer (score 0):

First I have found the location of the decimal using `strpos` function and increment the `strpos` postion value by 1 to skip the decimal place.

Second I have subtracted the whole string length from the value I have got from the point1.

Third I have used `substr` function to get all digits after the decimal.

Fourth I have used the `strlen` function to get length of the string after the decimal place.

This is the code that performs the steps described above:

```
     <?php
        $str="98.6754332";
        echo $str;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo substr( $str, -(strlen($str)-(strpos($str, '.')+1)) );
        echo "<br/>";
        echo strlen( substr( $str, -(strlen($str)-(strpos($str, '.')+1))) );
    ?>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain how your solution works.

Comment: @Stibu hi..i have updated the answer please check and let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: You added some text, which is definitely a good idea. Since I'm not familiar with PHP, I can not judge the contents of your post. I have tried to clean up the formatting and reworded your last sentence. If you do not agree with the changes, feel free to remove them or edit again.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any numbers, even in scientific notation, with precision up to 100 decimal places.

```
$float = 0.0000005;

$working = number_format($float,100);
$working = rtrim($working,"0");
$working = explode(".",$working);
$working = $working[1];

$decmial_places = strlen($working);
```

Result:

```
7
```

Lengthy but works without complex conditionals.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work at all. [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a190385ce2c93a596108800c3d1ad4cefb5a493d)

Answer (score -1):

```
$value = 182.949;

$count = strlen(abs($value - floor($value))) -2; //0.949 minus 2 places (0.)
```

Comment: I got a problem with precision on php in this test return 0.94900000000001

Answer (score -1):

You should always be careful about different locales. European locales use a comma for the thousands separator, so the accepted answer would not work. See below for a revised solution:

```
 function countDecimalsUsingStrchr($stringValue){
        $locale_info = localeconv();
        return strlen(substr(strrchr($stringValue, $locale_info['decimal_point']), 1));
    }
```

see [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)