# PHP - number_format issues

Tags: php, number-formatting

`number_format` **stupidly** rounds numbers by default.  Is there just a simple way to turn off the rounding?  I'm working with randomly generated numbers, and I could get things like...

42533 * .003 = 127.599 or,
42533 * .03 = 1275.99 or,
42533 * .3 = 12759.9

I need number_format (or something else) to express the result in traditional U.S. format (with a comma separating the thousands) and **not** round the decimal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add the expected result, too?

Comment: @AmalMurali: I would want **12759.9** to be displayed as **12,759.9**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [number_format](http://php.net/number_format) is the number of decimals in the number. The easiest way to find that out is probably to treat it as a string (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits)). Traditional US format is default behaviour, so you don't need to specify remaining arguments.

```
$num_decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($number, "."), 1));
$formatted_number = number_format($number, $num_decimals);
```

Comment: Seems to be working... Thanks.  Even though it's **RETARDED** that we even have to go through this.  It's stupefying as to why you can't turn off the rounding of number_format.

Comment: This does work, but it gives me values like 7.5 instead of 7.50. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested in this, I've written a little function to get around this problem.

With credit to Joel Hinz above, I came up with...

```
function number_format_with_decimals($value, $round_to){
    //$value is the decimal number you want to show with number_format.
    //$round_to is the deicimal place value you want to round to.

    $round_to_decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($value, "."), $round_to));
    $ans = number_format($value, $round_to);

    return $ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried these solutions, but what ended up being my answer was this:

```
$output=money_format('%!i', $value);
```

This gives you something like 3,234.90 instead of 3,234 or 3,234.9