# number_format inaccurate in PHP

Tags: php, precision, number-formatting, floating-accuracy, bignum

PHP function number_format seems to not be reliable for big numbers. It's probably a rounding issue as explained on [PHP - number_format issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071112/php-number-format-issues)

The function money_format() behaves similarly.

This is the case:

> $n = 1000000000000000001;
>
> echo "\nn = $n";
>
> $nFormat = number_format($n, 0, '.', ',');
>
> echo "\nnFormat = $nFormat";
>
> $nMFormat = money_format('%!i', $n);
>
> echo "\nnMFormat = $nMFormat";

Results are:

> n = 1000000000000000001
>
> nFormat = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000
>
> nMFormat = 1000000000000000000.00

Is there a number_format function for big numbers in PHP? Should I code myself? Do I have to deal with big numbers as strings for formatting?

Comment: Is your $n being treated as a float, or as an integer? If you're on 32bit PHP, that will exceed max int value, so it will be a float

Comment: How do I find that out? PHP is running on Ubuntu server: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-77-generic x86_64)

Comment: PHP_INT_SIZE = 8

PHP_INT_MAX = 9223372036854775807

Comment: Your answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6936191/3081659

Comment: I guess I need to use a big integer library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427020/is-there-a-biginteger-class-in-php to tackle such big numbers. Thx a lot!