# Prevent number_format from rounding numbers - add commas and keep the decimal point - PHP

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

Number format adds the commas I want but removes the decimals.

```
echo number_format("1000000.25");
```

This returns 1,000,000

I want it to return 1,000,000.25

I need both the commas and the decimals, without any number rounding. All my values are decimals. They vary in length.

Do I have to use something other than number format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case what you meant by *they vary in length* is related to the decimal part, take a look at this code:

```
function getLen($var){
    $tmp = explode('.', $var);
    if(count($tmp)>1){
        return strlen($tmp[1]);
    }
}
$var = '1000000.255555'; // '1000000.25'; // '1000000';
echo number_format($var, getLen($var));
```

---

Some tests

- Output for `1000000.255555`:

> 1,000,000.255555

---

Output for `1000000.25`:

> 1,000,000.25

---

Output for `1000000`:

> 1,000,000

---

It counts how many chars there are after the `.` and uses that as argument in the `number_format` function;

Otherwise just use a constant number instead of the function call.

---

And some reference...

---

From the [manual -> **number_format()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )
```

And you can see in the description that

> **number** 
>   The number being formatted.
>
> **decimals** 
>   Sets the number of decimal points.

And a bit more:

> [...]If two parameters are given, number will be formatted with decimals
>   decimals with a dot (".") in front, and a comma (",") between every
>   group of thousands.

Comment: You should return 0 as an else option for your getLen function: function getLen($var){
    $tmp = explode('.', $var);
    if(count($tmp)>1){
        return strlen($tmp[1]);
    }else{ return 0;}
}

Answer (score 10):

```
$number = '1000000.25';
echo number_format($number, strlen(substr(strrchr($number, "."), 1)));
```

**Explanation**:
Number Format takes a second parameter which specifies the number of decimal places required as pointed out in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits) Stack overflow answer tells you how to get the number of decimal places of your provided string

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of searching a way to get the len xD. Cool solution

Answer (score 3):

The docs for number_format() indicate the second parameter is used to specify decimal:

```
echo number_format('1000000.25', 2);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php