# Display thousand seperator integer into integer value using PHP function

Tags: php

I am working in my php function. My requirement is to convert :

```
1,234
```

into

```
1234
```

I know it can be achieved by **str_replace** but is any inbuilt PHP function exists for this or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://php.net/number_format as such:

```
number_format(1.234,3,'','');
```

and this will output:

```
1234
```

In addition, you could see this post [PHP: get number of decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits) to get a good idea on how to automate the second parameter of the above function.

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is not bad to do this. BTW, there is a multiple alternatives. You could use one of the from below:

**1 [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)**

```
$a = '1,234';
$a = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $a);
```

Regular expression for simple character substitution is overkill.

**2 [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)**

```
$a = '1,234';
$b = strtr($a, array('.' => '', ',' => ''));
```

You'd be better off using strstr. Above both example will help you.