# How to show decimal value after multiplication

Tags: php

I have value which stored in database like price. 123.00

When i tried to see the subtotal which is `quantity * price`.
So `123.00*1 = 123.00`
But in view it shows 123 instead of 123.00 where price showing like 123.00 in same table.
How can i show decimal value after multiplication?

Comment: [`number_format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: [`money_format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Comment: [`printf()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

Comment: [`sprintf()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: So many options if you were only to look at the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/docs.php) Its even written in many languages

Comment: How much [research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the number using number format PHP function. Consider

```
$price = 125;
$quantity = 1;   
echo number_format($quantity*$price,2);
```

You can also have extra comma separated values that set the decimal separator, i.e. "." and the thousands separator also i.e. ",". See http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php