# PHP Limiting Digits After Comma In Decimals Multiplication Result

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
$number_1 = 0.01;
$number_2 = 3.22321;
$result = $number_1 * $number_2;
```

and the result is : `0.0322321`

how to have decimal digits of `$result` same with `$number_1`, in this case, I'm expecting `0.03` (2 digits after comma).

**update** : `$number_1` doesn't always have 2 digits after comma. it's random.

Comment: `round($result,2)` php function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this :

```
<?php
$number_1 = 0.01;
$number_2 = 3.22321;
$result = $number_1 * $number_2;

$num_des = strlen(substr(strrchr($number_1, "."), 1));

echo round($result,$num_des);

?>
```

Comment: Source : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another option and after trying to remember some maths...

```
$number_1 = 0.01;
$number_2 = 3.22321;
$result = $number_1 * $number_2;
echo round($result,log10(1/$number_1));
```

Comment: Full math answer, I think it is the better.

Comment: This doesn't work if the number has more decimals. https://3v4l.org/TKFea

Comment: @Andreas not sure if a value for $number_1 of 0.01001 is in scope of what OP is asking - 0.00001 works, although even `$result = $number_1 * round($number_2);` works for this scenario.  With the various up and down votes going on it seems like a not particularly clear question and I think your answer is a more generic solution (hence the upvote).

Comment: My point was just to say something is not correct with the math or the math is not possible on all numbers. If that is in or out of scope is for the OP to answer. I'm more questioning why your answer doesn't work than pointing it out as an error. Thank you for the upvote I will gladly do the same to you it is a nice solution, even if it seems to fail at some numbers.

Comment: @Andreas, I am happy to be challenged as it's always possible to miss something, it may also give OP a heads up of potential issues.  As you know I will also challenge others and prefer to do so than downvote if the answer is viable/fixable.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of decimals in $number_1 and use it in number_format function.

```
$decimals = strlen($number_1) - strpos($number_1, ".")-1;

echo number_format($result, $decimals); //0.03
```

https://3v4l.org/fGW5N

Comment: @Nigel that was a copy paste error. My browser reloaded and removed my `-1`. It's corrected now

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT :** After your edit, the solution is : 
[PHP: get number of decimal digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430084/php-get-number-of-decimal-digits)

Like that :

```
round(0.0322321, strlen(substr(strrchr($number_1, "."), 1)));
```

---

```
echo round(0.0322321, 2);  // 0.03
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.round.php

Comment: well in this case, $number_1 doesn't always have 2 digits after comma.

Comment: How come this answer getting so much upvotes since this is not even op asked for ?

Comment: Because op wasn't clear about this meanning.

Comment: *how to have decimal digits of $result same with $number_1*. How is that not clear?

Comment: @Andreas *I'm expecting 0.03 (2 digits after comma).*

Comment: If you only read parts of the question then I understand why it's hard for you to understand the questions. The full sentence of what you cited is: ***how to have decimal digits of $result same with $number_1, in this case**, I'm expecting 0.03 (2 digits after comma).*

Comment: Often the OPs do not need complicated code because have just one context. I thought that $number1 has always 2 digits.

Comment: In the html tag that may be correct. Also worth knowing. Voting for close and giving answer is frowned upon at SO.

Comment: I see that because I googled @SupunPraneeth's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use `printf()`/`sprintf()`:

```
$val = 1.234;
printf('%.2f', $val);
```

or [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$val = 1.234;
echo number_format($val, 2, '.', '');
```